# How to access child elements using XmlResourceParser

Tags: android

I created an XML file and put it in my "res" folder.  I decided to use the XmlResourceParser to parse the XML file.

My question is, how do I move to the next level of elements?  Specifically, how can I access the child nodes?

Thanks

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<encounters>
    <creature id="1" type="humanoid" name="Jon" race="Human" gender="M" age="20" alignment="NE">
        <appearance condition="ragged" skinColor="white" hairColor="brown" size="M" height="70" weight="170"></appearance>
        <stats hp="20" ac="5" ap="5" mp="10" str="11" dex="15" int="15"></stats>
        <inventory wp1="sword" wp2="knife" arm1="leather" arm2="bracers"></inventory>
        <magic attSp1="fireball" attSp2="iceBall" defSp1="minor Shield" defSp2="major Shield"></magic>
        <treasureItems gp="10" sp="25" item1="ring of protection + 1"></treasureItems>
    </creature>
</encounters>
```

My code so far looks like this:

```
    //  ***** BEGIN XML PARSING ***** 
    try {
        while (xrp.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (xrp.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
                String s = xrp.getName();

                if (s.equals("creature")) {
                    encounterID = xrp.getAttributeResourceValue(null, "id", 0);
                    encounterType = xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "type");
                    encounterName = xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    encounterRace = xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "race");
                    encounterGender = xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "gender");
                    encounterAge = xrp.getAttributeResourceValue(null, "age", 0);
                    encounterAlignment = xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "alignment");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        // ***** END XML PARSING *****
```

Comment: getResource().getString() or something would be easier

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry I'm new to this and quite ignorant.  Do you mean getResource().getSring() is better than XmlResourceParser? Or do you mean instead of using XmlResourceParser.getName(), I should use getResource().getString()...Just out of curiousity, why would it be easier?  ---Thank you ---

Comment: if your file is in res, chances are you can access it via getResources() (though i'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here)

Comment: I have my data stored in the XML file.  And I'm trying to parse that XML file and assign the data within to variables in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is documentation on how to use the XmlPullParser [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).

That being said you want to use the xrp.next() function to move the parser to the next element. This will cycle through all the elements in your XML document in the order that they appear. If you have sub elements, the parser will reach those after touching the START_TAG of the parent element.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link.  Unfortunately I've already started my code using the XmlResourceParser.  Is the XmlPullParser better?  ---Thanks

Comment: Its the same thing. See the documentation for the XmlResourceParser, it implements the XmlPullParser interface.

Comment: Ok I've gone over the documentation...I see they are creating the XML file with new StringReader.  But I don't see any way to read in an XML file in my 'res' folder. ---Thanks

Comment: XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.yourXmlName);
All you need to do is add an xrp.next() after the end of your if statement to navigate through your entire XML document.

Comment: Hi Justin...I'm using the XmlPullParser now...do I need to switch back to the XmlResourceParser?  ---Thanks

Comment: They are the same thing.. You could use the following code. 
XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.yourXmlName)
XmlPullParser pullParser = xpp;

But that doens't matter. All you need to use is xrp.next() after the end of your if statement.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought they were different parsers.  --Thanks

Comment: Hey Justin, I used that code and I'm getting an error("the method getResources is undefined.") on this line: XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.Encounters); I have "import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;" up top...not sure why I am getting this...

Comment: It depends on where you are attempting to do this. IF you have a context reference, try context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.Encounters)